# MongoDB Index build process & Why does index creation blocks all the database activities

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I had to create indices for a collection. I created it but it affected all the requests on the other collections in the other database.

From doc, I read that index creation blocks all read/write locks on all the databases. What is the reason behind such behavior of mongo DB?

- Locking that collection is the best.
- Locking that database is acceptable.
- Locking all the databases is confusing me.

Comment: not sure why this question is being marked to close..

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to build indexes on MongoDB -

**1)** Foreground : If you're using MongoDB version <`4.2` all indexes are by default build Foreground, Which has better data structures & fast in process but major downside would be while indexes getting build it blocks all operations on database. Which has to be avoided on usual prod servers.

**2)** Background : So for all versions below `4.2` to overcome con of foreground build process of blocking database activities, there is an option `{background :true}` to build indexes in background, here while MongoDB is building indexes you can still do reads & writes but cons with this approach is the index structure is least performant & index build time is more.

For MongoDB v >= `4.2`, building indexes on background is deprecated, So you can no more specify it & take advantage of background indexes, So MongoDB itself internally builds indexes in background fashion but there would be a lock on the particular collection at start of index build & at end of the build, rest apart mostly you can go ahead with your reads & writes, but somehow there will be 'intent exclusive IX lock' which will intermittently lock the collection & after certain stages there will be lock on writes & then a complete lock, which will finally be released at the end. **But why ?** So this is to take advantage of fastness & better data structures of foreground + non locking mechanism of background build process.

**Ref :** [.createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) & [index-creation-process](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#index-operations)

Comment: Thanks for explaining with versions and background option is really useful